# How to get the server date (i.e month and day) in magento?

Tags: php, magento, date

Is there any magento way to get the server date i.e day and month? I have tried this:

`$today = date("m-d", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));`

this will return (For eg: 5-22), while i convert this date to (may 22) by

`$monthdates=date("M-d",$today);
 echo $monthdates;`

it is returning (Jan 22).I don't know how. Can anyone clarify it, or either can show any other method to achieve what is required?

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try:

```
$today = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are making mistake in passing argument in date() 2nd parameter should be time string and you are passing date.
It should be  like this:

`$monthdates = date("M-d",Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));`